# Excel VBA: how to set all Pivot Items that start with a certain character to false

Tags: excel, vba

how can set all Pivot Items that start with a certain character to false

i currently have a situation where i have a list of pivotitems that my macro has recorded but the problem is the code bombs out when new or different pivotitems are introduced into the data set:

```
 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Cause")
        .PivotItems("D101").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("D201").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("D401").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("D402").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("D405").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("L101").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("L102").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("L201").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("L203").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("L205").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("L207").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("L302").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("L401").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("L402").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("L405").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("L503").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("L601").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("L705").Visible = False
```

the one thing that these items have in common is that they either start with "D" or "L"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Cause")
        For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count - 1
            If .PivotItems(i).Name Like "D*" OR .PivotItems(i).Name Like "L*" Then
                .PivotItems(.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = False
            End if
        Next i
    End With
```

Comment: @SikhumbuzoNzimande Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the code below, explanation inside the code's comments:

```
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtFld As PivotField
Dim PvtItm As PivotItem

' set the Pivot-Table object
Set PvtTbl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7")

' set the Pivot-Field
Set PvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("Cause")

' loop through all Pivot Items in PivotField "Cause"
For Each PvtItm In PvtFld.PivotItems

    ' check the first letter of the Pivot Item's name
    Select Case Left(PvtItm.Name, 1)
        Case "D", "L"
            PvtItm.Visible = False
    End Select

Next PvtItm
```

Comment: @SikhumbuzoNzimande you're welcome, now comes your part where you mark as "Answer", by clicking the gray check mark on the left side of my answer